Interrupting a web service operation via button click
I am retrieving  data via method in web service class. I shouldn't tamper with this class as it is auto-generated. Is there anyway to interrupt this data retrieval operation via button event? I basically called this web service method ListAsync and hold the data in datatable like this(it is being triggerd via start event):
DataTable dtResult = await sapApi.ListeleAsync(new Range(dateFormatLow, dateFormatHigh), "", null, ""); 


By "interrupt" you mean "cancel" ? If the method does not support cancellation - usually by taking a CancellationToken argument - then you can only "kill" the thread, which you really do not want to do. You can of course wrap it in "fake" async and on cancelation abandon the task and ignore the result. But that won't actually stop the method from running.

Is my assumption correct: this takes too long and users want to cancel the query? I'd consider a common technique of anticipating the runtime to expect by running a heuristic on the query parameters. If it indicates an expected runtime longer than "x" then require the user to set the filter to be more restrictive.

Your assumption is correct,yes. Sometimes the query takes too long to respond therefore I want user to be able to cancel it via button. Also user cannot be always asked to be more restrictive about filter. So at the end of the day I really need to be able to interrupt this operation when it takes too much time to respond

OK: Then this is your "TODO": 1. Find out if there is an API that supports cancellation. 2. Optimize what you possibly can, so you minimize the need to do the cancellation. And 3. For the case there is no API that supports cancellation, find out if it is "ok" to have "canceled" calls run to completion and just ignore their return.

selam CuriousJunior1, Cancellation Token u need to check. But do not cancel without check :)
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/
BUT At here sapApi.ListeleAsync should support it afaics
